# Serialize a class using SpringLayout (Java)

Tags: java, serializable, springlayout

I recently started developing in Java and have enjoyed the experience a lot. The default Java package comes loaded with useful things, and having the Swing package has been a great help creating a GUI. I decided to use SpringLayout for my LayoutManager because it was simple and extremely flexible, but now down the road I'm finding myself in a pickle.

I would like to be able to persist the state of my application. I started to approach this with use of the Preferences API, but that only allows for the storage of Java natives (understandable - its goal is to be lightweight). I went ahead and bastardized the use of Preferences by persisting XML strings packed with data. After a while, I decided to look around and see if there was anything better, and then I got around to reading about serializable - looked like I had found my answer.

I hit a snag, however, when I tried to serialize a class that had some GUI components that were managed by SpringLayout, which I have come to find does not implement serializable. I thought I'd found my way around the issue with the `transient` keyword, but SpringLayout's only allowable modifier is `final`. The only workaround I've seen is to change which LayoutManager I'm using... which I'd rather not do as I've created some fairly customized GUIs.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any and all responses.

-M

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> SpringLayout's only allowable modifier is `final`.

If it is a field of your Serializable Object then you can declare it transient. If you do not have control over all fields in an Object, try persisting only a `State` Object where you write all data that is relevant. Persisting a layout manager is not a good idea.

Comment: Hmm... I found my issue - I was trying to declare local instances of SpringLayout as `transient`, rather than actual class variables... duh. But, why would persisting a layout manager that does implement `Serializable` a bad idea?

Comment: Most LayoutManagers do not have a state that needs to be serialized. For me serialization should target the underlying data and all UI should be constructed from ground up for every invocation of the program.

Comment: Understood. I've got some check boxes whose checked/unchecked states I'd like to preserve, so I'll persist those states and after construction of the UI I can simply set those states.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to declare instances of SpringLayout that were *local to the constructor* as `transient`. What needed to be done was to declare those variables as class variables and then modify them as `transient`.

Comment: I've gone through every class in my source package, and have preceded **every** declaration of SpringLayout with transient, and I am still getting a `java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.SpringLayout`. Any ideas?